# Is gravity of matter similar to temperature?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, quantum-electrodynamics, noise

Apart of general relativity and the quantum theory postulate o gravitons I am looking for an alternative quantum physical interpretation of gravity of matter?

Watching this short video-cut from Dyson's interview there is a phrase he says that has strike me immediately:

He says in some point of the interview that *"that gravity could be something similar to temperature"*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcicI_GJGcM&t=270s (watch at this time stamp)

**Is there a theory currently in the existing literature that supports this kind of view?**

I mean why not? Gravity actually reminds to an incoherent noise field. That would also explain why it more then 38 orders of magnitude less stronger than a coherent field like electromagnetism or the strong nuclear forces. You cannot quantize an incoherent field. Temperature is also a noise field, the net energy of the incoherent motion Brownian motion of all the atoms in a matter object.

So why not also gravity being an emergent macroscopic field of decohered quantum EM noise far field of matter?

As for the counter-argument, yes but in temperature we have directional flow of energy, hot (larger noise Brownian motion of atoms) to cold (less noise motion of atoms), we have this also in gravity!

From smaller gravitational mass (smaller quantum EM noise) to larger gravitational mass (larger quantum EM noise). Larger masses attract more smaller masses.

A mass object made of countless of trillions of atoms will  have no coherent magnetic dipole field  still it will have an incoherent magnetic noise field around it. This could interact at a distance with the magnetic noise field generated by another mass object in space and momentarily attract (free magnets always attract each other) the nearby mass bit by bit. Integrating this phenomenon over time gives as gravity.

Surely a thought you cannot dismiss lightly. Only incoherent energy like a noise field can be more than 38 orders of magnitude less stronger than a coherent directional field like electromagnetism.

Comment: See also [Entropic gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity)

Comment: This might help:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230881/how-is-the-temperature-of-a-star-related-to-gravity      http://pubs.sciepub.com/ijp/6/4/1/index.html#:~:text=1)%20Newton%27s%20universal%20gravitational%20value,the%20absolute%20value%20of%20gravitation.

Comment: I do not understand the down votes, why?

Comment: Bekenstein entropy seems temperature-like. Verlinde's theory of emergent gravity is information based. No gravitons are present. No big bang ever occured, and dark matter and energy are effects of informatiin in the volume and normal gravity is based on entropy increase on the surface at the horizon of the observable universe. I think he's got it backwards though. And galaxies without dark matter or the bullet cluster are hard to explain away in the model.

Comment: @foolishmuse Interesting paper that supports this hypothesis. Temperature could be seen as spin 1 EM radiated interacting noise and gravity as interacting spin 1/2 magnetic noise.

Comment: @foolishmuse Higher temperatures will result to higher incoherent quantum noise field with less coherent magnetic moments over time therefore less gravity.

Comment: The noise of gravitons
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7hzOZDdf38
At 33:10 of the video the GR-QFT mixed equation solution show that gravity is stochastic noise field!

Answer (score 1):

According to general relativity increased mass in any given location in space - such as a galaxy or super cluser - means that space is curved more than compared to empty regions of space. This curvature of space time carries inherent energy. So the more mass there is, the more space is curved, and the more energy exists in that region. We can phrase this as an energy density.

Temperature is a measure of *energy density*. This is to say that the hotter something is the more heat energy it has and so therefore the greater the thermal energy (heat) density.

Gravity is like temperature in the sense that there is an energy density associated with the theories. Could gravity be an emergent property of spacetime, de-cohered electroquantum chicanery, or the result of cold matter gaining more gravitational force compared to hot matter? Possibly, but I have no reason to believe it is. The paper that @foolishmuse linked is not particularly enlightening or special, but may be of relevance.